QSerialPort проблемы с динамическим изменением паритета
Реализую протокол получения данных от датчика давления.
Протокол следующий:

Устройству отсылается байт адреса. Отсылка производится с паритетом Mark (типа 9-й бит данных)
Затем, два байта адреса на странице памяти устройства. Отсылка производится с паритетом Space
Устройство должно ответить 4-мя байтами данных. Тоже с паритетом Space.

Все данные и адреса посылаются с кодом Хэмминга в младшей тетраде.
Посылаю два запроса:

Адрес: 77 Адрес на странице: 2E 4D
Адрес: 77 Адрес на странице: 31 4D

На первый приходит ответ, а на второй нет.
В ходе экспериментов выяснил, что устройство не отвечает только на адреса на странице являющиеся нечетными (1,3,5 и т.д). Решил поэкспериментировать и выяснил, что при передаче с паритетом Mark пакеты с байтом 0х55 в пакете бит паритета 1(как и должен быть), а, например, 0х51 бит паритета в пакете в 0-е(смотрел на осциллографе). Т.е. бит паритета зависит от передаваемых данных. Этого быть в принципе не должно! Mark и Space - паритеты не зависящие от передаваемых данных.
Вот пример кода функции:
FSerialPort->setParity(QSerialPort::Parity::MarkParity);
quint64 WriteRes = FSerialPort->write(ADevAddress,ADevAddressSize);
FSerialPort->waitForBytesWritten(100);

Res = FSerialPort->setParity(QSerialPort::Parity::SpaceParity);
WriteRes = FSerialPort->write(APageAddress,APageAddressSize);
FSerialPort->waitForBytesWritten(100);

QByteArray Buff;
if (FSerialPort->waitForReadyRead(300))
{
    Buff = FSerialPort->readAll();
    while (FSerialPort->waitForReadyRead(40))
    {
        Buff += FSerialPort->readAll();
    }
    // получили буфер и обработали
}

Помогите разобраться почему себя так ведет бит паритета и как добиться адекватной передачи данных?
Qt 5.15.2 - не могу использовать более старшие версии т.к. нужна поддержка Win 7

я бы взял st-link и прошил бы в него контроллер всю логику работы, а данные передавал по hid =)

Может быть, есть программа производителя устройства, которую можно запустить и отследить, что она делает?

нет. такой проги нет

А что возвращает setParity?

true - т.е. если я правильно понимаю, все прошло успешно

Проблема с этими устройствами, работающими на допотопных стандартах... Может быть, Odd и Even посылаются правильно? Тогда вам нужно посчитать биты 1 в каждом байте, и выставить такой Odd или Even, чтобы дал желаемый результат в Parity.

я понял Вашу идею. Попробую. Странное поведение с Mark|Space как объяснить?
